# Using Localizable.strings in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization, three20

I downloaded the three20 library:

http://three20.info/

And I opened the TTCatalog sample project that comes with this library:

http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/3183/screenshot20100302at752.png

As you can see, there are lots of Localizable.strings files.

When I opened the iPhone simulator and changed its language to for example French in the settings, the text on the button still remains in English:

http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/9775/screenshot20100302at812.png

I already checked that there is definitely a corresponding entry for the text "See All" in the Localization.strings of French.

Why and what are the steps to make it use the Localizable.strings files?

(This sample project does not come with any nib/xib file)

EDIT:

After adding the following XML in Info.plist:

```
...
<dict>
...
    <key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
    <array>
    <string>de</string>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>es</string>
    <string>fr</string>
    <string>it</string>
    <string>ja</string>
    <string>zh_cn</string>
    <string>zh_tw</string>  
    </array>
</dict>
...
```

It works now!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this thread help http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/bee3d5525a32d476 ?

Quoted text, in case the link becomes unavailable:

> For localizations inside bundles to work, your app has to have some localized resources itself, because the available localizations are determined by looking at the once available in the main bundle.  Alternatively, you can add the available localizations as a setting in your Info.plist, with the key 'CFBundleLocalizations'.  Note that the value of this key has to be an array, something the Info.plist editor of XCode does not support, you edit the file 'by hand' to get the localizations in there.  If you only need one localization, you can simple set the key 'CFBundleDevelopmentRegion' to the value of your choice.